# Xamarin Project not installing

Tags: xamarin

I have setup Visual studio and android studio on a new PC. I am getting this error when trying to deploy a Xamarin form project on an old (Android 5.0) device from visual studio.

*Error      XA0132: The package was not installed. Please check you do not have it installed under any other user.
If the package does show up on the device, try manually uninstalling it then try again.
You should be able to uninstall the app via the Settings app on the device.*

I have factory reset the device, but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this once.

Go to visual studio editor and make sure the checKbox next to Project Settings > Android-Options > Fast Deployment is not marked and try again.